# Parse How do I get an array of pointer from a column in swfit?

Tags: arrays, pointers, parse-platform, swift2, pfobject

My problem is here I have a class in parse named PapaList where I have the column hijos that is and array of pointers, now I can get that column but when I try to navigate to the pointers in there those have a nombre column in another class like this:

```
PapaList->
        |
        objectId(string) -> papa(Pointer<_User>) -> hijos(Array[pointer])
```

In Alumnos class (where the pointers are "pointing to"):

```
Alumnos->
       |
       objectId(string)->nombre(string)*...
```

This is the column I want for each of the pointers * but i have not found a way to go there.

I have done the following:

```
func findAlumnos() {

    if papa == PFUser.currentUser()! {

        let queryHijos = PFQuery(className: "PapaList")
        queryHijos.whereKey("papa", equalTo: papa)
        queryHijos.includeKey("hijos")
        print("papa = \(papa)")
        do {

            hijos = try queryHijos.findObjects()

            let hijosIdx = "hijos"
            let hijoOne = hijos[0][hijosIdx]
            print("hijos = \(hijos[0][hijosIdx])")
            print("primer hijo \(hijoOne)")

        } catch let error {

            print(error)

        }

    }
}
```

But this is not giving me a PFObject to index it with "nombre". It gives me what appears to be a string or an AnyObject.

```
primer hijo (
    "<Alumnos: 0x7a7d81d0, objectId: nDapd6fIVc, localId: (null)> {\n    apellido = Lopez;\n    faltas = 5;\n    fechaingreso = \"2015-09-18 06:34:00 +0000\";\n    fechanac = \"2015-09-17 02:56:00 +0000\";\n    grupoId = \"<Grupos: 0x7a7e3c80, objectId: 1kKmcDikef, localId: (null)>\";\n    matricula = A006;\n    nacionalidad = mexicana;\n    nombre = Juanito;\n    numlista = 2;\n}"
)
```

Any help here?? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, nested Parse objects are not returned with the top level query. If you have a class that has a single pointer to an object as a column, you can call use the `include:` method of PFQuery to also fetch that object. However, if you have an array of pointers, the only way to fetch the entire array is to pass that array into the `whereKey:containedIn:` method. In the iOS SDK, you can not pass an array of pointers, so you will actually have to iterate through your array of pointers, adding their objectIds to a separate array, then pass that array into `whereKey:containedIn:`.

http://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html
http://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/whereKey:containedIn: